# Is Project development possible in NAV 2016 similar to that of AX 2012?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-nav, dynamics-nav-2016

I had been working on AX 2012 and there while creating customized objects you maintain a "Shared Project" that help you in migrating the objects from one instance to another.

Recently I started learning the NAV 2016 concepts and there if one have to create customized objects and maintain it together for importing, exporting on different instance than is it possible to create Shared Project over there?

I have tried importing, exporting single and multiple objects together. The extension that they get converted into are .fob

If in case it is possible to create 'Shared Project' in nav 2016 than please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no built-in functionality to do this.

It is usually maintained by using separately maintained identifiers which are appended to the 'Version' string of an object whenever a change is made such that this column can be filtered in the object designer to identify objects that are part of 'projects.'

Say you carry out a modification with a reference of 'M001'.  You would append M001 to the version list of any objects you change or create as part of this modification.  When you are finished, you filter the 'Version List' field in Object Designer on `*M001*`, select all of the objects and export them.

Comment: So, suppose if I want to migrate multiple objects from one instance to another by comparing the changes in the objects than how it can be achieved in NAV 2016?

Comment: Updated the answer to clarify